# Drag and drop listwidget items with a combobox inside

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox, qlistwidget

I have two listwidgets in icon mode list1 is a list of 100 widget items (each Widget item is an icon packed with a combobox with 3-4 items inside) .
Those combobox items are data of the icon this will never change ,they are packed with the Widget item ,listwidget2 is empty and I just want to be able to drag the widget item(icon and combobox with items) from 1 and make a favorite list with some widgets of list1, nothing will change to combobox items or the widget items of list1 they will have always the same data,
the problem is that  each time I drag the widget only the icon is copied to the other listwidget.

```
 QDir dir ("icons");
 QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList(QDir::AllEntries | 
 QDir::Dirs|QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);

 for(int i=0 ; i < list.length() ; i++){
 dir_names.push_back(list.at(i).baseName());
 /*Setting the icon*/
 QIcon icon;
 icon.addFile(list.at(i).absoluteFilePath(), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, 
 QIcon::Off);
 QListWidgetItem *iconItem = new QListWidgetItem(ui->listWidget);
 iconItem->setIcon(icon);

 QComboBox *box = new QComboBox;
 QListWidgetItem *textItem = ui->listWidget->item(i);

 ui->listWidget->setItemWidget( textItem,box);
 box->setFixedHeight(18);
 box->addItem(list.at(i).baseName());
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the combobox to be moved you must overwrite the dropEvent method so you must create a class that inherits from QListWidget, get the widget and copy the necessary data. If you want to use it in Qt Designer you must [promote it](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html).

**listwidget.h**

```
#ifndef LISTWIDGET_H
#define LISTWIDGET_H

#include <QListWidget>

class ListWidget : public QListWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ListWidget(QWidget * parent = 0);
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent * event);

protected:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
};

#endif // LISTWIDGET_H
```

**listwidget.cpp**

```
#include "listwidget.h"

#include <QDropEvent>
#include <QComboBox>

ListWidget::ListWidget(QWidget *parent):QListWidget(parent)
{
    setDragEnabled(true);
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    setDefaultDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
}

void ListWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    if(event->dropAction() == Qt::MoveAction && event->source()){
        ListWidget *listWidget = qobject_cast<ListWidget *>(event->source());
        if(!listWidget)
            return;

        QList<QPersistentModelIndex> pIndexes;
        for(QModelIndex index: listWidget->selectedIndexes()){
            pIndexes << QPersistentModelIndex(index);
        }

        std::sort(pIndexes.begin(), pIndexes.end());

        QListWidgetItem *item = itemAt(event->pos());
        int rowStart = item? row(item) : count();

        for(QPersistentModelIndex pindex: pIndexes){
            int r = QModelIndex(pindex).row();
            QComboBox *input = qobject_cast<QComboBox *>(listWidget->itemWidget(listWidget->item(r)));

            QComboBox *output;
            if(input){
                // move data to QComboBox
                output = new QComboBox;
                for(int i=0; i<input->count(); i++){
                    output->addItem(input->itemText(i));
                    output->setCurrentText(input->currentText());
                }
            }

            QListWidgetItem *it = listWidget->takeItem(r);
            insertItem(rowStart, it);
            if(input)
                setItemWidget(it, output);
        }
        setState(QAbstractItemView::NoState);
    }
}

void ListWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    setState(QAbstractItemView::DraggingState);
    QListWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48729828) there is an example.

Comment: eyllanesc thanks a lot for the code it helped me a lot . It works for moving items but not for copying .Just trying now to figure out how can I drag the items from list1 and drop it to list2 without erasing it from list1  .Is it something simple that I am missing or it requires a lot of extra code? I think this line ` listWidget->takeItem(r);` removes the item from list1